WiFi Security Settings [WEP]?
Have just started a course in Ethical Hacking.
The plan is to use a Raspberry Pi-4 (32-bit Lite, Bookworm, Headless) which I have already configured it as an Access Point to use as a target:
$ sudo nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid <hotspot name> password <hotspot password> ifname wlan0
    
$ sudo nmcli connection modify <hotspot UUID> connection.autoconnect yes connection.autoconnect-priority 100

By default, the network security would be WPA/WPA2.
As I am in the early stage of this course - it is still discussing gaining access to a network configured as WEP.
How do I modify the existing Wifi Security settings for the Pi4 to reflect WEP?

Welcome.  Since we don't know how you configured the Pi as an access point, we can't tell you how to modify that configuration.  Also note that since AP software is not unique to the Pi, this question is probably better asked on Unix & Linux.

Thanks for the welcome goldilocks. Yes, I should have included the process I performed.
After updating/upgrading the system files, I issued the following command via a SSH session.
$ sudo nmcli device wifi hotspot ssid  password  ifname wlan0
$ sudo nmcli connection modify  connection.autoconnect yes connection.autoconnect-priority 100
Reboot
And that is all I have done.

Okay.  Next time please edit such details the question.

I managed to find a manual that covers the NetworkManager for 'nmcli'.
As it turns out, the 'key-mgmnt' no longer supports WEP or WAP.
After some further investigation I found RaspAP, which turns your Raspberry-Pi into a Router.
This gave me what I needed to allow me to use the Pi for my Ethical Hacking attacks.
